# Android : Failed looking up window

Tags: android

I have an android app that I am minimising and opening another app (temple run 2). If I go back to my app immediately, it resumes my app. This is the behaviour I want. However, if I go back to my app after approx 30 secs, my app restarts instead of resuming. Is there some place (maybe AndroidManifest), where I can set this time?

> 08-26 16:58:48.025: W/WindowManager(2269): Failed looking up window
>   08-26 16:58:48.025: W/WindowManager(2269):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window
>   android.os.BinderProxy@42fe4540 does not exist
>   08-26 16:58:48.025: W/WindowManager(2269):    at
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8911)
>   08-26 16:58:48.025: W/WindowManager(2269):    at
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8902)
>   08-26 16:58:48.025: W/WindowManager(2269):    at
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:934)
>   08-26 16:58:48.025: W/WindowManager(2269):    at
>   android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:449) 
>   08-26 16:58:48.025: W/WindowManager(2269):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

Comment: Absolutely not, the Android lifecycle is the core system for handling activites and apps. You should instead gracefully check inside your app which callback you receive, `onResume` or `onRestart`, and then act act accordingly